# Stripping actions from ANTLR grammar changes its parsing algorithm

Tags: antlr, grammar, antlr3, xtext

I have a grammar `Foo.xtext` (too complex to include it here).  Xtext generates `InternalFoo.g` from it.  [After some tweaking](http://eclipse.org/Xtext/documentation/indigo/new_and_noteworthy.php) it also generates `DebugInternalFoo.g` which claims to be the same thing without actions.  Now, I strip off actions with ANTLR directly

```
java -cp antlr-3.4.jar org.antlr.tool.Strip Internal.g > Stripped.g
```

I'd expect the three grammars to behave the same way when I check them.  But here is what I experienced

- `InternalFoo.g` - error, rule assignment has non-LL(*) decision
- `DebugInternalFoo.g` - no problem, parses fine
- `Stripped.g` - warnings at rule assignment, decision can match using multiple alternatives. It fails to parse properly.

Is it possible that a grammar parses a text differently with or without actions?  Or is it a bug in any of the action-remover tools?  (The rule in question has syntactic predicates, and without them, it would really have a non-LL(*) decision.)

UPDATE:

I partly found what caused the problem.  The rule in question was like this

```
trickyRule:
  ({ some complex action})
  (expression '=')=>...
```

Stripping with Antlr removed the action, but left an empty group there:

```
// Stripped.g
trickyRule:
  () (expression '=')=>...
```

The generation of the debug grammar removes both the action, and the now empty group around it:

```
// DebugInternalFoo.g
trickyRule:
  (expression '=')=>...
```

So the lesson learned is: an empty group before a syntactic predicate is not the same as nothing at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible that a grammar parses a text differently with or without actions?

Yes, that is possible. `org.antlr.tool.Strip` leaves syntactic predicates<sup>1</sup>, but removes validating<sup>2</sup>- and gated<sup>3</sup> semantic predicates (and `member` sections that these semantic predicates might use).

For example, the following rules would only match an `A_TOKEN`:

```java
parser_rule1
  :  (parser_rule2)=> parser_rule2
  ;

parser_rule2
  :  {input.LT(1).getType() == A_TOKEN}? .
  ;
```

but if you use the `Strip` tool on it, it leaves the following:

```java
parser_rule1
  :  (parser_rule2)=> parser_rule2
  ;

parser_rule2
  :  /*{input.LT(1).getType() == A_TOKEN}?*/ .
  ;
```

making it match *any* token.

In other words, `Strip` could change the behavior of the generated lexer or parser.

---

<sup>1</sup> syntactic predicate: `( ... )=>`
<sup>2</sup> validating semantic predicate `{ ... }?`
<sup>3</sup> gated semantic predicate `{ ... }?=>`